# parsing a c-string with odd tokens

Tags: c, parsing

I'm trying to parse a line like

```
1            {2}           {2,3}         {4}
```

into 4 different character arrays

where 1 is '1','\0'

and the other numbers in brackets are each 
'2'

'2','3'

'4'

I've tried strtok with dilems " \t}" and I've also tried sscanf passing it %s for the first column and "{%S}" for the remaining columns. Neither are giving me expected results.  Can anyone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: This could be a job for regular expressions...

Comment: Is there a nul char between all arrays ?

Comment: @Kwariz nope tabs and spaces also the first 'name' column can be longer than one character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `%S` parses a space terminated word (so it reads the '}' as part of the string.

```
fscanf(stream, "{%[^}]}", buffer);
```

Will scan the characters between '{}' into a buffer.
Note: you may also want to be careful about buffer overflow here.

```
"{%[^}]}"
{             -> Matches {
%[<char>]     -> Matches a sequence of characters that match any of the characters in <char>
                 If the first character is ^ this makes it a negative so any characters that
                 do not follow the ^
%[^}]         -> Matches a sequence of characters that does not match `}`
}             -> Matches }
```

But I would try and parse the numbers out individually.

```
// If the input does not contain '{' next then we get an error and the
// next section of code is not entered.
if (fscanf(stream, " {") != EOF)
   // Note: The leading space matches one or more white space characters
   //       So it is needed to get passed leading white space.
{
    // We enter this section only if we found '{'
    int  value;
    char next;
    while(fscanf(stream, "%d%c", &value, &next) == 2)
    {
        // You have an integer in value
        if (next == '}')
        {    break;
        }
        if (next == ',')
        {    continue;
        }
        // You have an error state  the next character after the number was not
        // a space or a comma ',' or end of section '}'
    }
}
```

#### Edit (to show in use)

With this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    while (scanf(" {") != EOF)
    {   
        printf("Enter BLOCK\n");

        int  value;
        char next;
        while(scanf("%d%c", &value, &next) == 2)
        {   
            if ((next == '}') || (next == ','))
            {   
                printf("\tVALUE %d\n",value);
            }   

            if (next == '}')
            {    break;
            }   
            if (next == ',')
            {    continue;
            }   

            printf("ERROR\n");
            exit(1);
        }   
        printf("EXIT BLOCK\n");
    }   
}
```

Then use like this:

```
> gcc gh.c 
> echo "  {2}           {2,3}         {4}" | ./a.out
Enter BLOCK
    VALUE 2
EXIT BLOCK
Enter BLOCK
    VALUE 2
    VALUE 3
EXIT BLOCK
Enter BLOCK
    VALUE 4
EXIT BLOCK
```

Comment: I tried to parse individually like you suggested, but the buffer doesn't seem to advance. I'm using sscanf not fscanf if that makes a difference.  So what happens, I still pass the if statement, but the next sscan gives me 1\t instead the beginning of the line instead of the next set of numbers.

Comment: Had to combine with this solution to use sscanf but it works, thanks http://stackoverflow.com/a/10827039/384306