# In C, parsing a string of multiple whitespace separated integers

Tags: c, string, file, parsing, io

I am attempting to use C to parse a file containing multiple rows of whitespace separated integers into a dynamic array of dynamic int arrays. Each row will be an array in the array of arrays. The number of rows, and elements in each row are non-constant.

What I have done so far is to use fgets to grab each line as a string.

I cannot, however, figure out how to parse a string of whitespace separated integers.

I thought I could use sscanf (because fscanf can be used to parse a whole file of whitespace separated integers). However, it appears that sscanf has different functionality. sscanf only ever parses the first number in the string. My guess is that, because the line is a string is not a stream.

I've looked around for a way to make a stream out of a string, but it doesn't look like that is available in C (I am unable to use nonstandard libraries).

```
char* line;
char lineBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
FILE *filePtr;
int value;
```

...

```
while((line = fgets(lineBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, filePtr)) != NULL) {

    printf("%s\n", lineBuffer);

    while(sscanf(lineBuffer, "%d ", &value) > 0) {
        printf("%d\n", value);
    }
}
```

Is there something that I can use to parse a string. If not, is there an alternative to this whole system? I would prefer not to use REGEX.

Comment: You can use e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the string on the space, and then use either [`sscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to get the value.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826953/sscanf-doesnt-move-scans-same-integer-everytime-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503135/get-number-of-characters-read-by-sscanf. I'm voting to close as duplicate because the answers there are answers to your question.

Comment: Also note that the `"%d"` format skips leading whitespace, so no need to do it manually in the format.

Comment: Another possibility is to use `sscanf` to scan *strings*, and then increase the pointer you pass to `sscanf` by the length of the string.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, the questions I linked do just that. The answers there provide a solution to his question as well.

Comment: @sashoalm  Agree about the duplication in http://stackoverflow.com/q/10826953/2410359 yet the FP example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13503135/get-number-of-characters-read-by-sscanf is sufficiently different.  Certainly the `sscanf()` approach is similar, Yet techniques to use `strtol()` for an  `int` and  `strtod()` for double have different set-up and test criteria.   Also other methods to parse integer are simpler that `double`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [strtol()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) which gives a pointer to the end of the match if there is one, and a char pointer to store the current position:

```
    while((line = fgets(lineBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, filePtr)) != NULL) {

    printf("%s\n", lineBuffer);
    char* p = lineBuffer;
    while(p < lineBuffer+BUFFER_SIZE ) {
        char* end;
        long int value = strtol( p , &end , 10 );
        if( value == 0L && end == p )  //docs also suggest checking errno value
            break;

        printf("%ld\n", value);
        p = end ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read a line via `fgets()` is a great first step.

2 methods: `strtol()` (better error handling) and `sscanf()`

```
while((line = fgets(lineBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, filePtr)) != NULL) {
  char *endptr;
  while (1) {  
    errno = 0;
    long num = strtol(line, &endptr, 10);
    if (line == endptr) break;  // no conversion
    if (errno) break;  // out of range or other error

    #if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN || LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
    // long and int may have different ranges
    if (num < INT_MIN || num > INT_MAX) {
      errno = ERANGE; 
      break;  // out of range
    }
    #endif

    int value = (int) num;
    printf("%d\n", value);
    line = endptr;
  } 
  while (isspace((unsigned char) *endptr)) endptr++;
  if (*endptr != '\0') Handle_ExtraGarbageAtEndOfLine();
}
```

" sscanf only ever parses the first number in the string." is not quite so.  Use `sscanf()` with `"%n"` to record where scanning stopped.

```
while((line = fgets(lineBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, filePtr)) != NULL) {
  int n;
  while (1) {  
    n = 0;
    int value;
    if (sscanf(line, "%d %n", &value, &n) != 1) break;
    printf("%d\n", value);
    line += n;
  } 
  if (line[n] != '\0') Handle_ExtraGarbageAtEndOfLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strtok()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) function with `" "`(space) as delimeter and place this in a loop that terminates when `strtok()` returns `NULL` to get each token then print each number from each token:

```
while((line = fgets(lineBuffer, BUFFER_SIZE, filePtr)) != NULL) {

    printf("%s\n", lineBuffer);

    char *token=strtok(line," ");

    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        if(sscanf(token, "%d", &value) > 0)
             printf("%d\n", value);
         token=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop over the input line, exploiting that atol() stops at the next whitespace delimiter anyway. Works well for positive integers only ;) But it is fast, you need not read tons of strtok and sscanf documentation and it is even robust in the presence of "noise" littered between your integers.
To make it work for negative ints, too, replace isdigit() with !isspace() and there you go.

```
void bla()
{
    const char * input = "    1           3           4       6     ";
    size_t i;
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            printf("%d\n", atol(&input[i]));
            while (i < len && isdigit(input[i]))
                ++i;
        }

    }
}

void bla1()
{ // positive and negative ints version
    const char * input = "    10           -3           42       6     ";
    size_t i;
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (!isspace(input[i]))
        {
            printf("%d\n", atol(&input[i]));
            while (i < len && !isspace(input[i]))
                ++i;
        }
    }
    /* Output: 
        10
        -3
        42
        6

    */
}
```

The next part of your question was (implicitly), how to handle dynamic arrays to store your parsed int values in. Here a solution which is based on the code above. The chunkSize is set too small for the input so I could test if the realloc code section also works.

```
typedef struct DataRow_tag
{
    int32_t *data;
    size_t length;
} DataRow_t;

// Returns a "bool" in C-style. Yes, there is stdbool.h in ansi c99 but it is disadviced.
// (Platform dependent trouble in the context of C/C++ interaction, often across library/DLL boundaries.
// Especially if you compile C with a C-compiler and the C++ code with C++ compiler. Which happens.
// Every now and then, sizeof(c++ bool) != sizeof(C bool) and you waste a lot of time finding the problem.)
// The caller takes ownership of the DataRow_t::data pointer and has to free() it when done using it.
// 0: false -> fail
// 1: true -> success!
int 
ReadRowWithUnknownNumberOfColumnsOfInt32
    ( const char * row      // Zero terminated string containing 1 row worth of data.
    , DataRow_t *result     // Pointer to the place the data will be stored at.
    )
{
    int success = 0;
    size_t chunkSize = 10; // Set this value to something most likely large enough for your application.

    // This function is not cleaning up your garbage, dude ;) Gimme a clean result structure!
    assert(NULL != result && NULL == result->data);
    if (NULL != result && NULL == result->data)
    {
        result->length = 0;
        size_t rowLength = strlen(row);
        const char *pInput = row;
        const char *pEnd = &row[rowLength-1];

        result->data = (int32_t*)malloc(chunkSize * sizeof(int32_t));
        if (NULL != result->data )
        {
            for (; pInput < pEnd; ++pInput)
            {
                assert(pInput <= pEnd);
                assert(*pInput != 0);
                if (!isspace(*pInput)) // ultra correct would be to cast to unsigned char first...says microsoft code analyzer in paranoia mode.
                {
                    long lval = atol(pInput); // what is a long anyway? 4 bytes, 2 bytes, 8 bytes? We only hope it will fit into our int32_t...
                    // TODO: we could test here if lval value fits in an int32_t...platform dependent!
                    result->data[result->length++] = lval;
                    if (result->length == chunkSize)
                    { // our buffer was too small... we need a bigger one.
                        chunkSize = chunkSize + chunkSize; // doubling our buffer, hoping it will be enough, now.
                        int32_t * temp = (int32_t*)realloc(result->data, chunkSize * sizeof(int32_t));
                        if (NULL == temp)
                        { // realloc is a funny function from the dark ages of c. It returns NULL if out of memory.
                            // So we cannot simply use result->data pointer for realloc call as this might end up with a memory leak.
                            free(result->data);
                            result->length = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result->data = temp;
                        }
                    }
                    while (pInput < pEnd && !isspace(*pInput))
                        ++pInput;
                }
            }
            if (pInput >= pEnd)
                success = 1;
            else
            { // make sure we do not leave result in some funny state.
                result->length = 0;
                free(result->data); // free(NULL) legal. If memblock is NULL, the pointer is ignored and free immediately returns.
                result->data = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

    return success;
}
void Bla2()
{
    const char * input = "-10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13";
    DataRow_t dataRow = { 0 };
    if (ReadRowWithUnknownNumberOfColumnsOfInt32(input, &dataRow))
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < dataRow.length; ++i)
        {
            printf("%d ", dataRow.data[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        free(dataRow.data);
        dataRow.data = NULL;
        dataRow.length = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there auto-down-vote bots around? Got -1 before my browser even loaded after hitting the "post" button...

Comment: @chux in that case you need to apply the last line of the answer text ;)

Comment: @chux and btw...it does advance in those cases. Only -123 is returned as 123. The while is inside the if and as such it is already past any '-' or '+'.

Comment: Yes, if you want to have negative ints, the robustness suffers ;) `` 123`` is no problem - why would it be?

Answer (score -1):

You should use :

```
lineBuffer = (char *)malloc(sizeof(BUFFER_SIZE + 1));
```

than :

```
char lineBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

Your stack will thanks you !

Comment: Not necessarily true. In 32-bit Linux, for example, there can be [more space for the stack than there is for the heap.](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Tuning_and_Optimizing_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_for_Oracle_9i_and_10g_Databases/sect-Oracle_9i_and_10g_Tuning_Guide-Growing_the_Oracle_SGA_to_2.7_GB_in_x86_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_2.1_Without_VLM-Linux_Memory_Layout.html)  And in 64-bit memory models, you'll almost certainly run out of actual memory before you run out of available heap or stack address space. Nevermind the heap performance hit.

Comment: You are totally right @AndrewHenle, thank for notice