# Reading an arbitrary number of space-separated chars from a line in file

Tags: c, fgets, strtok

I have a file, which, at one line has an arbitrary number of numbers to be read as integers. In a minimal, reproducible example, I created a file `test.dat` that contains the following line only:

```
 1 2 3 4
```

I then try to use `fgets` and `strtok` to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

FILE* fileptr;

fileptr = fopen("test.dat","r");
char line[500];
char *token;

int array[20];
int i = 0;

fgets(line,300,fileptr);

token = strtok(line," ");
array[i] = atoi(token);
printf("%d\n", array[i]);
i++;

while(token != NULL){
    token = strtok(line," ");
    array[i] = atoi(token);
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

But this results in printing 21 lines of `1`'s, followed by 632 lines of `0`'s. Finally it gives a segmentation fault because the `i` grows larger than 20, the allocated space for `array`. What I don't understand is why 600+ lines are printed, and why I can never read beyond the number `1` in the file. What am I missing?

Note: I prefer to keep reading from the file with `fgets` because this is going to be a simple modification to an existing subroutine that reads an entire file.

Comment: Hmmm, Unclear why 300 in `fgets(line,300,fileptr);`.  I'd expect `fgets(line,sizeof line,fileptr);`

Comment: @chux No good reason -- I didn't write original code where that line came from. I'll fix it. Thanks.

Comment: If the goal is to get "space-separated chars", then `strtok()` is fine.  Yet since that token is immediately run thorough `atoi()`, using `strtol()` instead of `strtok()/atoi()`makes more sense as in [parsing a string of multiple whitespace separated integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28233450/2410359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- You're not limiting your loop to the capable magnitude of `array`
- Your loop is not structured properly. All storage should be done within the loop; the outlier prior need not be there.
- Your invocation of `strtok` within the loop is wrong. A *continuation* of an initial onset of `strtok` should specify `NULL` as the first argument. See documentation for [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) for more information and usage examples.

An example that addresses these problems is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fileptr = fopen("test.dat","r");
    if (fileptr == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to open file: ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char line[500];
    int array[20];
    const size_t max_size = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
    size_t i = 0;

    if (fgets(line,300,fileptr))
    {
        char *token = strtok(line," ");
        while (i < max_size && token != NULL)
        {
            array[i] = atoi(token);
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
            ++i;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        // use array and i for whatever you needed
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. What's the logic behind passing `NULL` into `strtok` after the first call?

Comment: @sodiumnitrate See [the documentation of `strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). It will do a far better job of explaining the purpose of that than I would, and give you an excellent site to bookmark for future queries in the process.