# C fscanf line to array

Tags: c, io

Say I'm reading an input file, and I have a line which is just five integers separated by spaces like:

```
4 12 1
```

And if want to store these in an array I'd use something like

```
fscanf(fileName, "%d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]);
```

(I'm new to C so please correct the above if that's not quite right)

However, this gets very clunky if I had even more integers on a line and wanted to store those in an array like

```
4 12 1 132 66 47 77 32
```

Is there a way to use a loop to read and store the first integer on the line, second integer, and so on?

Comment: Are you familiar with `fgets()` for reading a _line_ of input?

Comment: @chux im not super familiar with that function, how would I use that in this case?

Comment: Review [In C, parsing a string of multiple whitespace separated integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28233450/2410359)